# Postgres Multiplication between Columns and Sum of result

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a data table with the following:

`Price   | Date    | Quantity
   20    | 01-02   |  1
   20    | 01-03   |  2
   30    | 01-01   |  2
   30    | 01-03   |  1
   40    | 01-02   |  3`

For each row, I would like to be able to multiple the value of the "Price" column with the same row's Quantity value, then sum those values, and return a single value to determine total revenue for the month.

Here is what I have, but I keep getting stymied:

`select sum(
  Select ("Price"*"Quantity") as "Subtotal") as "Total"
from Sales
where "Date" between '01/01/2016' and '01/31/2016';`

However, this doesn't appear to do the trick.  Does somebody know how I might tweak it to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum("Price"*"Quantity") as "Total"
from Sales
where "Date" between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31';
```

You can directly apply `sum` on the product of `"Price"`, `"Quantity"` fields. The above query returns a single row.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e73ad/3)